# Sum a number with divisors to get another number

Tags: algorithm, math

There are two numbers A and B, in each step we can sum A with one of divisors expect 1 and A. We want to get from A to B, what is the minimum step that we can get B? Sometimes we can't get B from A print -1.I want an algorithm that solve this problem.

Edit: Consider Z=A in each step sum Z with one of the divisors Z expect 1 and Z to get B

4<=A<=B<=100000

Example: A=4, B=24

4->6->8->12->18->24

As you can see the answer is 5 for this example.

Comment: Nothing, I don't have any idea to solve this problem

Comment: "sum A with one of divisors" -- one of the divisors of *what*? A? B? Both? In any event -- why not do a breadth-first search? Implicitly, you are trying to find the shortest path in an acyclic directed graph.

Comment: What happens when it's not possible? e.g. A = 3, B = 5?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a homework completion site. It's also about math and not programming as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Comment: @KenWhite I agree that it should be closed (I picked "too broad" as the reason) but don't think that is off-topic since it is asking about an algorithm to solve a (somewhat artificial) combinatorial optimization problem. Language-agnostic questions about algorithms are not on-topic.

Comment: @JohnColeman: It's a paraphrase of a homework assignment, that makes  no mention of any code or effort to write code, includes no programming related details, and includes a [tag:math] tag. There's a site for math related questions. It's at [mathematics.se]

Comment: @KenWhite sometimes we can't get B from A and should be print -1 in output

Comment: @JohnColeman Consider Z=A in each step sum Z with one of the divisors Z expect 1 and Z to get B

Comment: @JohnColeman I think that the issue of language agnostic algorithms questions hasn't been resolved. There are a lot of them here, and there isn't a better overflow board for them. Many of the language specific algorithms questions are only incidentally language specific. I agree with closing this, but not because it's an algorithms question.

Comment: When you write "we can sum A with one of divisors expect 1 and A" do you mean "we can add A with one of the divisors of A except 1 and A"? Also, have you done any programming with graphs (also called networks), so you can understand the first comment by John Coleman?

Comment: @RoryDaulton Yes,I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this using dynamic programming

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define INF 1000000007
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int dp[101] = {0};
    int a,b,i,j;
    scanf("%d%d",&a, &b);
    for(i=a;i<=b;i++)
        dp[i] = INF;
    dp[a] = 0;
    for(i=a; i<=b; i++){
        for(j=2; j*j<=i; j++){
            if(i%j == 0){
                dp[i+j] = min(dp[i+j], dp[i]+1);
                dp[i+i/j] = min(dp[i+i/j], dp[i]+1);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", dp[b]);
    return 0;
}
```

dp[i] would update all the i+j where j is a factor of i

> Complexity O(n*sqrt(n))

check it out in the [online compiler](https://ideone.com/labUid)

Comment: Why did you answer such a poor question--hard to understand, clearly a rewrite of a homework assignment, where the asker shows no effort and does not answer all clarifying questions asked in the comments? That does not even include the discussion of whether such a question is off-topic for this site.

Comment: @RoryDaulton: Really it's down to the answerer to assess that. This question will almost certainly be closed, and possibly deleted. The answerer loses any reputation earned, and only 10k members can see it. The answer itself is, IMHO, pretty good (hence my upvote), although it is lacking in supporting documentation. I also take issue with the `#define` and the potential for out of range array element access.